# In prayer and glorifying Hashem: Is thanks an expression of praise? Is praise an expression of thanks?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilla, hashkafah-philosophy, thanksgiving

I am pursuing a line of thought.

According to [this](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.109.30), they seem to be linked (yet still separate):

> **א֘וֹדֶ֤ה** ה' מְאֹ֣ד בְּפִ֑י וּבְת֖וֹךְ רַבִּ֣ים **אֲהַלְלֶֽנּוּ**׃
>
> My mouth shall sing much **thanks** to Hashem;
> I will **praise** Him in the
> midst of the multitudes (Tehillim 109:30)

JPS, for example, translates א֘וֹדֶ֤ה as "praise", not thanks. This is one example of many where praise and thanks seem to be blurred.

*[Neither here nor there?: Sometimes in english, as an expression of thanks, we use the idiom "you're the best", which is actually an expression of praise.]*

So the question, a bit hard to state, is:

Are praise and thanks intertwined? To what degree? Are there any sources that cover this in depth? Even better, one that covers all words related to glorification of Hashem!

Comment: thanks would be gratitude for something specific while praise is saying declaring Hashem to be wonderful without needing to be connected to anything that was received. Praise is also related to admittance which is a form of humbling one's self before another such as admitting someone else was right. Here in terms of Hashem we ar humbling ourselves before our Creator with our praise to him. I'm not looking at it now but something like this is what I remember from a book titled "As for my my prayer" by Nisen Mindel regarding "hodu"

Comment: The thanks and admittance/confession concept that @Dude mentions is famously discussed by Rav Hutner